# Android app works on emulator but will not install on my phone

Tags: android, apk

I am teaching myself to program android apps, i wrote a simple tip calculator as a starter project. The program runs fine on the emulator, but when i export an apk file it wont install on my phone. i transferred the file with out adb because adb wont detect the device. i am on ubuntu 12.04, i have the vendor code in udev rules, the device is Huawei Ascend (M860)
how can i find a log of what went wrong. or an idea of what i did wrong.

this is the main java file:

```
package com.groundscore.gstipcalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Constants used when saving and restoring

private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

private double billBeforeTip;   // Users bill before tip
private double tipAmount;   // Tip amount
private double finalBill;   // Bill plus Tip

EditText billBeforeTipET;
EditText tipAmountET;
EditText finalBillET;

SeekBar tipSeekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// Inflate the GUI

    // Check if app just started, or if it is being restored        
    if(savedInstanceState == null){

        billBeforeTip = 0.0;
        tipAmount = .15;
        finalBill = 0.0;

    } else {
        // App is being restored

        billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
        tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
        finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);

    }

    // Initialize the EditTexts

    billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
    tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
    finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalEditText);

    tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);

    tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarChangeListener);

    billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

        tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;

        tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


};

private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        try{

            billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
        }

        updateTipAndFinalBill();

    }


};



private void updateTipAndFinalBill() {

    double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());

    double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);

    finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
    outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
    outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".GsTipCalc" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/billTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/bill_text_view" >
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="5"
    android:hint="@string/bill_edit_text"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/finalEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billTextView"
    android:ems="5"
    android:hint="@string/bill_edit_text"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/finalTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/finalEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalEditText"
    android:text="@string/final_text_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:progress="15" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SlideTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/finalEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
    android:text="@string/change_tip_text_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Logcat read out from the install attempt:

```
I/ActivityManager( 7588): Starting: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/GsTipCalc.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 14921
I/ActivityManager( 7588): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +347ms
D/dalvikvm(14940): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 50% free 2696K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 275ms
W/ActivityManager( 7588): No content provider found for: 
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec list
I/PackageHelper(14940): Size of container 2 MB 234323 bytes
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec create smdl2tmp1 2 fat {} 10022
W/logwrapper(14978): Unable to background process (No such file or directory)
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: warning, /dev/block/dm-2 is not a character device
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): /system/bin/newfs_msdos: Skipping mount checks
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): Bogus heads from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): Bogus sectors from kernel - setting sane value
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): /dev/block/dm-2: 4176 sectors in 522 FAT32 clusters (4096 bytes/cluster)
I//system/bin/newfs_msdos(  207): bps=512 spc=8 res=32 nft=2 sec=4221 mid=0xf0 spt=63 hds=64 hid=0 bspf=5 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=2
I/Vold    (  207): Filesystem formatted OK
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec path smdl2tmp1
I/PackageHelper(14940): Created secure container smdl2tmp1 at /mnt/asec/smdl2tmp1
I/DefContainer(14940): Created container for smdl2tmp1 at path : /mnt/asec/smdl2tmp1
I/DefContainer(14940): Copied /mnt/sdcard/GsTipCalc.apk to /mnt/asec/smdl2tmp1/pkg.apk
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec finalize smdl2tmp1
I/DefContainer(14940): Finalized container smdl2tmp1
I/DefContainer(14940): Unmounting smdl2tmp1 at path /mnt/asec/smdl2tmp1
D/dalvikvm(14940): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 50% free 2695K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 71ms
D/dalvikvm( 7588): GC_EXPLICIT freed 227K, 38% free 6615K/10631K, external 609K/1800K, paused 169ms
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec unmount smdl2tmp1 force
W/ActivityManager( 7588): No content provider found for: 
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec mount smdl2tmp1 {} 1000
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec path smdl2tmp1
D/PackageParser( 7588): Scanning package: /mnt/asec/smdl2tmp1/pkg.apk
E/PackageParser( 7588): Package com.groundscore.gstipcalc has no certificates at entry res/layout/activity_main.xml; ignoring!
I/PackageHelper( 7588): Forcibly destroying container smdl2tmp1
D/dalvikvm( 7588): GC_EXPLICIT freed 135K, 39% free 6530K/10631K, external 609K/1800K, paused 169ms
D/VoldCmdListener(  207): asec destroy smdl2tmp1 force
D/dalvikvm( 7588): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 39% free 6528K/10631K, external 609K/1800K, paused 245ms
```

Comment: What's the error message when trying to install the APK on your phone?

Comment: cant get an error, because i cant get adb to connect and there is none on the phone, i created a unsigned apk and transferred it by usb

Comment: i am on ubuntu 12.04, i have the vendor code in udev rules, the device is Huawei Ascend (M860)

Comment: I am posting the logcat info from the install attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have used "Project Right Click -> Android Tools -> Export ***Unsigned*** Application Package" and inadvertently created an unsigned APK.
Unsigned APKs will *not* run on neither the emulator nor actual device. When you run the app from Eclipse to an emulator, the APK is signed with a debug certificate, so in this way the APK is still signed.

The fastest way to get an APK to be transfer to your device would be go to dir /bin, there should be an APK there which is refreshed everything you've changed something AND has run the changes on the emulator.

[Reference 1](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/10)

Comment: in the bin folder of the project? because i can't find it there.

Comment: Run the project on the emulator at least once, and the APK that will be installed on the emulator will be stored there.

Comment: i figured out how to sign it with the debugging.keystore in ~/.android with an alias: androiddebugkey Password:android

Comment: Hmmm of course you can sign the APK yourself, but that becomes a hassle quite fast. I would still recommend you to figure out how to get the APK in /bin without manual signing or get your device to show up in ADB, which should be the long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone appears on the devices list??

For you know, go to your adb installation and run the adb tool

you_path\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools

```
adb devices
```

This should list your devices connected to your tool.

Make sure the emulator is down.

Comment: i created a api file and transferred it by usb. when i tried to install it via eclipse it did not show up on the device list

Comment: What is device that are you using? Did you installed all the drivers? Are you using Windows?

Comment: i am on ubuntu 12.04, i have the vendor code in udev rules, the device  is Huawei Ascend (M860)

Comment: Test with to run adb commands as root (`sudo`) and see what happens.

Comment: i managed to connect adb manually to the logcat of the device and posted the output from the install attempt

Answer (score 1):

May be , There will be a problem in your `minSdkVersion` , `targetSdkVersion` !

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

minSdkVersion="8" : for android 2.3

targetSdkVersion = "17" for android 4.1

your phone is  Lower SDK , and your .apk file is created with Higher SDK .

Comment: no, it is higher than the minSdk, and smaller than the targetSdk, my min is 2.2 and my target is 4.2 and the phone is 2.3. thank you for the reply though

Comment: i managed to connect adb manually to the logcat of the device and posted the output from the install attempt

Comment: i figured out how to sign it with the debuging.keystore in ~/.android with an alias: androiddebugkey  Password:android